# Ruby on Rails factoring help conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with pull review and asks me to factor the following code, someone can help me with this?

```
  @start_time = (params[:start_time].to_time.hour.to_i < @room.opening_time.hour.to_i)? @room.opening_time.hour_minutes : params[:start_time]
  @end_time = (params[:end_time].to_time.hour.to_i > @room.closing_time.hour.to_i)? @room.closing_time.hour_minutes : params[:end_time]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question with  more detail about the problem you have and the desired outcome. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you could throw some of the crazy long chains you're comparing into variables like so

```
opening_time = @room.opening_time.hour.to_i
closing_time = @room.closing_time.hour.to_i
starting_time = params[:start_time].to_time.hour.to_i
ending_time = params[:end_time].to_time.hour.to_i
open_minutes = @room.opening_time.hour_minutes
close_minutes = @room.closing_time.hour_minutes
```

Then you can do

```
@start_time = starting_time < opening_time ? start_minutes : params[:start_time]
@end_time = ending_time > closing_time ? end_minutes : params[end_time]
```

Which is a lot more readable.

From there I would recommend extracting out to two methods to run the actual conditionals, to make it clearer in English what the code is trying to do. For example:

```
def get_start_time(time)
  starting_time = time.to_time.hour.to_i
  opening_time = @room.opening_time.hour.to_i
  open_minutes = @room.opening_time.hour_minutes
  starting_time < opening_time ? start_minutes : time
end

def get_end_time(time)
  ending_time = time.to_time.hour.to_i
  closing_time = @room.closing_time.hour.to_i
  close_minutes = @room.closing_time.hour_minutes
  ending_time > closing_time ? end_minutes : time
end

@start_time = get_start_time(params[:start_time])
@end_time = get_end_time(params[:end_time])
```

Which, while it may be more physical code, is a lot clearer and simpler to read, which is a huge part of refactoring, especially when working with a group.